# Using LAMP With Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: permissions, lamp

So, I'm using Ubuntu desktop and have installed Apache, PHP and MySQL, all working great.

I want to use start adding files and folders to /var/www using the file manager, but my user doesn't have permissions to do this.

Any ideas what permissions I need to update?

Comment: Consider Setting up a [Virtual Host](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/httpd.html), and make the host point to /home/<username>/public_html/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www
```

The user should be able to edit /var/www/ without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Create a directory in your home, ie:

```
mkdir ~/my_dir
```

then, create a symbolic link in `/var/www/`:

```
ln -s ~/my_dir /var/www/my_dir
```

This allows you to write to the directory. If apache needs to access, you must change the group to all the directories where you want this to happen:

```
sudo chown -R <user>:www-data ~/my_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also start nautilus as root:

```
sudo -i nautilus &
```